# GCD of more than 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, math

```
function gcd (a, b) {
    if(b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}

function gcd_more_than_two_numbers (a) {
    var last = Math.max.apply(null, a);
    var first = Math.min.apply(null, a);    

    return gcd(first, last);
}

console.log(gcd_more_than_two_numbers([9999,213123,9,15,27])); 
console.log(gcd_more_than_two_numbers([5,10,15,25]));
```

Is it right to take the lowest and the highest values in an array and find a gcd for all the numbers between them ? Is it mathematically right ?

Comment: No. Take following example: `[100, 13000, 1110]`. With your logic, GCD would be `100` but in reality, it would be `10`

Comment: Absolutely right! Have to work more on my math skills i think.

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes i saw it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it right to take the lowest and the highest values in an array and find a gcd for all the numbers between them ? Is it mathematically right ?

**NO**.

---

You need to take the gcd of the first pair and then recalculate against all the other elements of the array, you can do that easily with `reduce`:

```js
function gcd (a, b) {
    if(b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}
function gcd_more_than_two_numbers (a) {
  return a.reduce(gcd)
}

console.log(gcd_more_than_two_numbers([9999,213123,9,15,27]))
```

Comment: Than you very much :)

Comment: @ТомаТомов glad that helped !

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't.

The identity you're after is `gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c)`.

I suggest you *unpick* the recursion using a loop.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    function gcd() {
      var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        if (b == 0) {
          return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b);
      });
    }
    console.log(gcd(7,14));
    console.log(gcd(9999,213123,9,15,27)); 
    console.log(gcd(5,10,15,25));
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done. This would help everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.every` as well to check validity:

#### Sample

```js
function getGCD(arr) {
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var gcd = 1;
  for (var i = gcd + 1; i <= min; i++) {
    if (arr.every(x => x % i === 0))
      gcd = i;
  }
  return gcd;
}
var arr = [100, 13000, 1110];
var arr2 = [9999, 213123, 9, 15, 27]
console.log(getGCD(arr))
console.log(getGCD(arr2))
```